# How does mining work?

Tags: naruto-online

So essentially I clicked on the new feature "mining" and my characters just stand there and there's a countdown. There was no real explanation for what exactly this is supposed to do.

Somehow it's linked with treasured tools but I can't seem to find any information besides "use some ore to power them up" so I'm looking for clarification on how all of this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bullet points!

- Mining is located in the Home menu at the bottom right. It takes 24 hours to mine once.
- Mining gives you ores to make / upgrade your treasured tools.
- The mines go up in level as you mine, so keep that timer going! The higher the level, the better ores you can mine.
- You can also steal from a random person's mine, but they have people guarding it! So should you! This is automatically done when you go to mine.
- Once your mines get to a higher level (just keep mining), you can mine more than one at a time!